# Is there any way to model this grouping process?

Tags: probability, modeling

I've been working on this problem for three days now, and it doesn't seem that it can be solved using pure thinking. Maybe there is some distribution that can model this but I couldn't find any solution till now.

This is the process I'm trying to model: I have $K$ points randomly dispersed in an area of radius $R$ using 2D-poisson random variable. I start by putting the first point in a group. Then, the distance $d$ between the first and the second points is found. If this distance is larger than a certain threshold ($Dth$) then the second point will be put in the same group as the first point. Otherwise, the second point will be put in a group alone. The process continues until the last point $K$.

A point will be put in a group if it has its distance from all the points in that group larger than $Dth$.

I've derived $P(d>Dth)$ which is the probability that two points have a distance between them larger than $Dth$, so let's denote it by $p$, and $P(d<Dth)$ by $q$.

What I want to find is either the average number of groups resulting given $K$ points (don't care about the radius $R$ because it is incorporated in the given probabilities) or the average number of points per group given $K$.

Comment: Do you need an analytical solution or a piece of code?

Comment: You write "then the distance between the _first_ and the _second_ point is found". So even though the points are dispersed in space, still they are indexed $1,...,K$, _before they are dispersed_, and you consider distances only following the index sequentially? Also is $Dth$ one symbol, or a product that we should know something about?

Comment: Thank you both for responding. Momo, I need an analytical solution. Alecos, yes I index the points and after that I model their locations using 2D-Poisson. The distances has no relation with the index. Dth is one symbol denoting the threshold distance.

Comment: It seems there is an internal consistency problem with your formulation. Denote $d_{ij}$ the distance between points $i$ and $j$. Assume we are at point 3. Assume first that points 1 and 2 are in different groups. It may be the case that both $d_{13}$ and $d_{23}$ exceed the threshold. In which group should point 3 be placed, since it is eligible for both existing? Maybe the answer is that we measure the distance of each point only from its predecessor? (i.e. we measure only $d_{23}$? (CONTINUED)

Comment: (CONTD)...But if this were the case, then assume that points 1 and 2 are in the same group: in order to determine whether point 3 should join them or be placed in a separate group, we must measure both $d_{13}$ and $d_{23}$. So we arrive at the internal consistency problem: if for each point we must measure the distance from all its predecessors, then indeterminacies may arise (case in previous comment). If we are to measure the distance only from its predecessor, then we cannot apply the criterion stated for joining a group. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: That is why I'm indexing the points before modeling their locations. This is a sequential process, so in your example point 3 will be put in group 1 because it has be tested with point 1 before point 2 regardless to the positions of the points.

Comment: I find the distance of a certain point with all other points following the indexes. If the distance between the point of concern and another point is higher than the threshold, then I test it with all the other points in the same group of that point. If all the distances are higher than the threshold then I put that point in that group.